# jsoup - Capturing <h1> elements excluding those that have the value &nbsp;

Tags: java, header, web-crawler, jsoup, element

I'm using a crawler to capture data from a website.
Now, I'm trying to select all of the `<h1>` elements, and print it (for now). I noticed that there are some headers that contains `&nbsp;` only which makes the data looks empty.

I want to exclude `<h1>`s with the values `&nbsp;`.

Here's what I have tried:

```
`private static void getAllH1(String url, Element tCon) {
//      System.out.println("Url: " + url);
        Elements headers1 = tCon.getElementsByTag("h1");
        System.out.println("Url\t\tHeader");
        for(Element h1: headers1) {
            if(h1.text().length()!=0 && h1.text()!="\u00a0") {
                System.out.println(url + "\t\t" + h1.text());
            }
        }
    }`
```

**EDIT:** I saw from one of the threads here about jsoup reading `&nbsp;` as `\u00a0` but it's still not working.

Here is an example output:

```
`
Url     Header
http://www.url.com/index.asp        Quick Links
http://www.url.com/index.asp        What's New
http://www.url.com/index.asp         
http://www.url.com/index.asp        What's Next
http://www.url.com/index.asp        What's On
http://www.url.com/index.asp        Key Rates
http://www.url.com/index.asp        Public Advisories
```

`
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer from this link:

[Element.text() doesn't normalize ' ' whitespace #529](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/529)

So what I did, from jsoup-1.9.2, I updated my jsoup into jsoup-1.11.2.
Then, when I run the code (same code; no alteration), it finally recognized the `&nbsp;`.